# Execute a Remote 32 Bit PSSession with elevated rights

Tags: powershell, remote-connection

So I'm trying to get a script to run a script from a server remotely on another server. This session has to be 32 bit because of a cmdlet. And the script has to be run as admin.
I've tried this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName isg108-81 -FilePath C:\inetpub\scrip\ConvertAppvPackages.ps1 -ConfigurationName microsoft.powershell32 -credentials Admin
```

So this starts the 32 bit version of powershell, but as soon as the script gets to the part where it needs elevated rights the shell tells me:

```
You must run this cmdlet using a Windows PowerShell elevated command prompt . To run
an elevated command prompt, right-click the Windows PowerShell or Command Prompt Start
menu object that you are using to start your Windows PowerShell sessions, and then 
Select Run as administrator.
```

Anybody got any ideas?

Thnx a lot for your help!

Comment: That's odd because remoting sessions normally run elevated already which is why you need admin credentials to initiate a remoting session.

Comment: Is there any way to switch to elevated mode while the script is running? @KeithHill

Comment: The only way to switch to elevated mode is to use `Start-Process powershell.exe -arg 'c:\blah\script.ps1' -verb runas`.  That assumes the user has admin privileges but is running with a standard user token in UAC.  You can also use the -Credentials parameter instead of `-Verb runas` to run as a different user that does have admin privs.

Comment: If you have access to the remote machine, I would stick in `$pid;Start-Sleep -secs 120` right before the command that fails.  When the pid is returned, log onto the remote machine, pull up task manager, find the pid (should be the WinRM hosting process) and look to see if the process is elevated.  Note you will probably have to add that column in details view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that the ConverFrom-AppvLeagcyPackage cmdlet somehow is broken and can't be executed remotely. As a solution I used the program Psexec to run the script remotely, although it only works if you run it as the system user.

Thank you non the less for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the server is a 64 bit OS, you'll have to call the 32 bit powershell.exe. What if you Invoked the server to run the 32 exe and run the script? Since your invoking it the program won't show up and the script would have to output some file to see any results.